# Continue url parameters to href next url

Tags: html, parameters, href

I have a static website with simple web pages. What I want to implement is, if user come to the website using

`example.com?param=abcd`

& I have a `href`

```
<a href="/findoutmore.html">
   Find Out More
</a>
```

So once the user clicks the href he should go to `example.com/findoutmore.html?param=abcd`

Basically I want to take the `params` to the next page too. Can I do it only using `href`? Or else what is the easiest way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes .You can do it like that.But will need to create a dynamic webpage which will handle the parameter using get request and do the further operation.**

Comment: Do you have any example for me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

**EXAMPLE 
To edit employee details by employee id**

    `<a href='EditEmployeeDetails.jsp?Id="+rs.getString("Id")+"'>Edit</a>` 

**Dynamic webpage to handle the request**

```
  <%
  if(request.getParameter("Id")!=null)
  {     
   //DB CONNECTION
   //FETCH DETAILS FOR THAT PARTICULAR EMPLOYEE ID
   //DISPLAY THE EMPLOYEE DETAILS       
  }
 %>
```